# Change the system.io.port datareceived event output type

Tags: c#, serial-port, .net, modbus

I am building a class library for modbus and serial connections, I need to return an array of bytes back but when using the DataReceived event from System.IO.Ports I cannot return any since it's type is void. Also, I am noticing that the DataReceived is not firing. The following is my code:

```
        public void ConnectSerialModBus_Loopback(string COM, int baud, int meter_address, int function, int Code_HighByte, int Code_LowByte, int data_high_byte, int data_low_byte)
    {
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort(COM, baud);
        try
        {

            if (!(port.IsOpen))
            {
                byte[] sendPacket = BuildPacket(meter_address, function, Code_HighByte, Code_LowByte, data_high_byte, data_low_byte);
                double dataBytes = 2.0;

                port.Open();
                port.RtsEnable = false;//rts = high
                port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
                //SEND PACKET TO DEVICE
                port.Write(sendPacket, 0, sendPacket.Length);

                #region RECEIVE DATA FROM SERIAL
                //MAKE DELAY TO SEND
                Thread.Sleep(10);

                port.RtsEnable = true;
                //MAKE DELAY TO RECEIVE
                port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
                //Thread.Sleep(CalculateDelay(dataBytes)+90);

                port.Close();
                port.Dispose();
                #endregion

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (port != null)
            {
                if (port.IsOpen)
                {
                    port.Close();
                }
                port.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort port = (SerialPort)sender;
        byte[] readingbyte = new byte[port.BytesToRead];
        if (port.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            port.Read(readingbyte, 0, readingbyte.Length);   
        }
    }
```

in some way I want to return the bytes received either from the `port_DataReceived` or from the `ConnectSerialModBus_Loopback` also the DataReceived is not firing.  Please help this is very urgent

Answer (score 22):

**DataReceived is not firing**

The DataReceived is not firing because you call `port.Close()` immediately after attaching the handler and before the SerialPort's receive thread has had a chance to run.

**Return an array of bytes back - Simple answer**

In the simple code sample you provide, you could create a private `Byte[]` member and assign the `readingbyte` object to it from within your `port_DataReceived` event handler.

**Return an array of bytes back - OO hint answer**

However, in a more rubust application, you should consider creating a Transaction class that encapsulates the Modbus ADU protocol parts, handling both the transmission of the client request and (layer 2) processing of the server's response.

In addition to the ADU layer, you would separate the PDU layer into an abstract ModbusFunction base class that provides an interface for the ADU class to get the request bytes and return the response bytes.  Then each modbus function that you want your client to use will be realised in a class of its own that derives from the PDU base class.

That way, when you need to interact with the server you create an instance of a PDU function class, with the appropriate parameters to form the correct PDU data packet, and pass it to the Transaction object that handles the request/retry/response logic and passes the returned data back to the PDU object to parse appropriately.

The addition of an event to the PDU base class will allow other parts of your code to attach to the PDU class's event and receive notification when the function has completed succesfully.

With a server that has multiple addressable properties, implemented by way of Modbus functions, you would create an instance of the appropriate Modbus Function class for each property (or set thereof for contiguous registers, for example) and attach to the event, updating your Model and/or UI whenever the object raises its update event.  Hook the UI commands to pass the Properties Modbus Function objects to the Transaction object if you want to query the server manually, or implement a timer thread that does it on a schedule if you want the properties to be polled on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

Do not sleep the datareceived event.

When the event fires place the bytes in a queue. You will need methods that the UI can use to piece the chunks of bytes back together.

See [SerialPort101](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/a709d698-5099-4e37-9e10-f66ff22cdd1e) for more detail on this.